# How to get a list of only community wiki questions?

Tags: support, search, community-wiki

Community wiki questions provide a generic view about some problem or situation. I always find reading community wiki questions more interesting compared to specific questions about some problem. Is there some way to get a list of community wiki questions sorted by popularity, views or up-votes? I am unable to find a community-wiki tag!

Comment: Add wiki:1 to the search - see http://stackoverflow.com/search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search with:

```
wiki:1 is:question
```